# How to append the data in a table using "interface" ? in Angular 6 using Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I'm very new to angular. I'm trying to make an API call in angular 6 using Typescript. I got stuck in appending data in a table.

see: [Codepen](https://codepen.io/venkatguru/pen/bmMWYL)

I'm using an angular material table that contains a `PeriodicElement` interface, an array, `const ELEMENT_DATA: PeriodicElement[]`, and a component class.

I don't know how to append to `ELEMENT_DATA` from within the class, because it is outside of the class.

Can anyone help me out with this issue?

Comment: angularjs _isnt_ the same as angular

Comment: also, you append data the same way as a normal array

Comment: Below link might be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52656937/in-angular-7-how-do-i-populate-a-mat-table-with-a-data-from-an-object/52657233#52657233

Comment: Please don't confuse AngularJS with Angular2+ - Here are some posts that elaborate on the differences: [Link1](https://dzone.com/articles/learn-different-about-angular-1-angular-2-amp-angu) & [Link2](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-difference-between-AngularJs-and-Angular-2)

Comment: @Shahana Thank you so much i was stuck in this issue from morning itself . it works for me thanks once again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue and fix it. Please see https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhngg8 for the solution.

Steps I've done:

1. Moved `ELEMENT_DATA` into class
2. Defined in the html `displayedColumns`

```
<tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></tr>
<tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></tr>
```

3. Added in the component: `providers: [HttpClient],`
4. Added in the module: `imports:[ BrowserModule, FormsModule, MatTableModule, BrowserAnimationsModule, HttpClientModule ],`
5. in the response you don't need foreach since your data is an array `subscribe((response: any) => this.dataSource = response.data[0])`

Comment: Thank you so much @ssuperczynski